# Node.js: Pipe ouput of request into crypto.hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, cryptography, request

I would like to compute the hash of a resource (e.g., a PDF) from a URL. To this end, I wrote

```
const computeHash = co.wrap(function* main(url) {
  const response = yield promisify(request)(url);
  // assume response.status === 200
  const buf = new Uint8Array(response.arrayBuffer);
  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
  hash.update(buf, 'binary');
  return hash.digest('hex');
});
```

to be used

```
const hash = yield computeHash('http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.1234v3.pdf');
```

What I like about the code:

- It's a generator, so I can `yield` it. Just a step away from `async`/`await`.

What I don't like:

- It doesn't correctly compute the hash. :)
- The `request` is completed and the response body as a whole piped into the `hash` function.
  I'd rather pipe the output of `request` into the hash function.

Any hints?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't correctly compute the hash? What are you comparing against?

Comment: The `sha1sum` computed locally. And it always computes the same hash, no matter the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crypto.createHash()` provides a [`Hash`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash) instance that currently supports two interfaces: legacy (`update()` and `digest()`) and streaming. You don't have to do anything special to use either one, so to stream the response to the hashing stream it's as simple as:

```
var hasher = crypto.createHash('sha1');
hasher.setEncoding('hex');
request(url).pipe(hasher).on('finish', function() {
  console.log('Hash is', hasher.read());
});
```

That's how you'd do it with normal callbacks, but I am not sure how you'd work `yield` into that as I'm not familiar enough with generators and the like.

Answer (score 1):

with modern async/await, you can now use the `stream/promises` builtin:

```
const streamp = require('stream/promises');
const hasher = crypto.createHash('sha1');
await streamp.pipeline(request(url), hasher);
console.log('Hash is', hasher.digest('hex'));
```

for co, just replace `await` with `yield`